# how to detect image tag in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display data using factory. I am able to show data in view but I have one issue: Actually I am getting data in `<img>` tag. I don't want to show this `img` tag in my column. I want to detect if it is `<img`, and if so I want to get its `src` value. If that value is `flag_red.gif`, then I need to set `backbground` `red`. If it is `flag_green.gif`, I need to set green background. Can we set this using `ng-if` in AngularJS? Can we detech `<img` tag in AngularJS?

here is my code

```
   function callServiceForLocalData() {
    acservice.callDisputeServiceLocal(function(data) {
        showViewAfterSuccess(data)
    }, function(data) {
        console.log("error on callTaskListServiceLocal");
    });
}
```

Comment: In your last sentence/question, do you mean 'detect' rather than 'detach'?

Comment: it is detect..sorry do you have any idea

Comment: the best way forward is a custom directive and a json containing two values, one the url, and one the color.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to control the display based on a positive or negative image, I wouldn't derive that information solely from the url of the image you are passing to it. In fact, I wouldn't pass the src of the image in data anyways. That aside, I have 2 options that I think may help.

Using CSS, you can use the src property to have specific styles. This is awkward and I wouldn't necessarily suggest this, but it would look something like

```
img[src='flag_red.gif]{
    background-color: red;
}
```

The other way that I would prefer would be to pass simple a positive or negative piece of data instead of the actual markup you are trying to display. For example in your JSON you have

```
value: "<img src="/img/samples/flag_red.gif" alt="red" height="16" width="16" border="0"/>"
```

When you could pass

```
value: 'negative'
```

and simply use the value to display the markup you want with an ng-if or ng-show

```
<img ng-show=' value == "negative" ' src='/img/samples/flag_red.gif' />
```

EDIT:

Another way ( if you have no control over the json data coming through ) would be to actually parse the string you get in value for an ' src=" ' and use the value.

Something like

```
if( value.indexOf('src="') > -1)
    var newValue = value.split('src="')[1].split('"')[0];
}
```

would give you

```
/img/samples/flag_red.gif
```

Comment: could you please use plunker

Comment: I am not going to rewrite the broken portions of your application in plunker, Im simply giving you high level snippets that you can implement trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding escaped HTML inside your database is a *terrible* strategy.  You're storing

```
     "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Contact_Risk__c",
      "value": "<img src=\"/img/samples/flag_red.gif\" alt=\"red\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" border=\"0\"/>"
```

6 months from now when you want to redesign your page to have a 24 pixel flag, you're screwed.  It would be much less fragile to store something like

```
     "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Contact_Risk__c",
      "value": "red"
```

and put the `<img>` HTML in your template instead.   (The field name 'fieldNameOrPath' implies deeper problems, but I'm not going to wade in there.)  (Even red / green is probably too specific, this might want to be a plain old boolean.)

That aside, one strategy here would be to use ng-class to control your display based on an object value:

```
<div class="col  (...etc...)" ng-repeat="i in task_column_name" ng-if="i.checked"
ng-class="{
redBackground: column[i.fieldNameOrPath]=='your db string here',
greenBackground: column[i.fieldNameOrPath]!='your db string here'}">...</div>
```

(and set .redBackground and .greenBackground descriptions in your CSS.)

Alternatively, use ng-if or ng-switch to draw different DOM nodes depending on the column value.